# ExtJS Button text change

Tags: extjs

I am designing a button in **ExtJS** with text `Show`, when I click on `button`, I want to change text as `Hide`

How can I handle this.

Plz Help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the click event of the button and change the text to "Hide".

```
listeners : {
    click: function(button,event) {
        button.setText('Hide');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you work with mvc then you will use this code

```
'widgetName button[text=Show]': {
    click: function(button, el) {
        button.setText('Hide');
    }
}
```